# Python List Conversion to string and split

Tags: python, string

Any Idea when I do the split on list( after converting to string) I am not getting the first and the last elements in the list....

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    lst1= ['3 6 2 5'];
    lst1=str(lst1);
    a = [int(i) for i in lst1.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
    print(a);
```

Outputs

[6, 2]

What I am looking for is

[2,3,5,6]

I think its due to the split characters which it finds after the 3(first element), but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Print `str(lst1)` to see what the problem is.

Comment: Probably you want `lst1[0]` instead.

Comment: Print lst1 returns  ['3 6 2 5'] which is the original list

Comment: Why are you converting `lst1` to a string in the first place? It contains a string as the element, use that.

Comment: i understand. its part of something i am trying to do .. a lot going on afterward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.

```
lst1= ['3 6 2 5'];
a = [int(i) for i in lst1[0].split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Comment: yeap,, this worked...  :)

Answer (score 2):

When you convert `lst1` to a string, you get

```
"['3 6 2 5']"
```

When you split this, you get the list: fir

```
["['3", "6", "2", "5']"]
```

`"['3".isdigit()` and `"5']".isdigit()` are false, so it doesn't print those elements.

To get the result you expect, you should not convert the list to a string. You should index the list to get its elements.

```
for s in lst1:
    a = [int(i) for i in s.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
    print(a)
```